# Does the maximum RPM of a massive spinning disk depend linearly on the material's tensile strength?

Tags: solid-state-physics, material-science, rotation

Assuming the material is homogeneous and isotropic.

Comment: No. Stress in a flywheel depends on square of rotation speed.

Answer (score 1):

In a given element of the disk, with a distance $r$ from the centre, length $\Delta r$, and cross section $r \Delta \theta$, the balance of forces are:

$$r \Delta \theta ( \sigma_{r+\Delta r} - \sigma_{r}) = \mu r \Delta \theta \Delta r \omega^2 r$$

Dividing by $r \Delta \theta \Delta r$ and taking the limit when $\Delta r->0$:

$\frac{d\sigma}{dr} = \mu \omega^2 r$

Integrating from zero to r:

$\sigma = \frac{\mu \omega^2r^2}{2}$

So, the max. RPM depends on the square root of the tensile strength.